# preg_replace is not working

Tags: parsing, function, preg-replace

I want to convert every pattern >>'number' (eg: >>4) on users' threads automatically to

```
<a href="#4">&gt;&gt;4</a>
```

So I made this function but it's not working.

Could you tell me what is wrong with the function?

```
function autolink($content) {
$pattern = "/>>[0-9]/i" ;
$replacement = "<a href=\"#\\0\">>>\\0</a>";
return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content, -1);
```

This function works well. This function automatically converts the urls into clickable hyperlink. I don't know why the first function isn't working.

```
function autolink2($contents) {
   $pattern = "/(http|https|ftp|mms):\/\/[0-9a-z-]+(\.[_0-9a-z-]+)+(:[0-9]{2,4})?\/?";       // domain+port
   $pattern .= "([\.~_0-9a-z-]+\/?)*";                                                                                                                                                                                             // sub roots
   $pattern .= "(\S+\.[_0-9a-z]+)?"       ;                                                                                                                         // file & extension string
   $pattern .= "(\?[_0-9a-z#%&=\-\+]+)*/i";                                                                                                                                                                               // parameters

   $replacement = "<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>";
   return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $contents, -1);}
```

Comment: This may be a long shot, but what about putting `&gt;&gt;` in your `$replacement` instead of those last two `>>`? Also, you may want to consider the case where the number is more than one digit, i.e. `>>10` . You could use regex `"/>>[0-9]+/i"` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function autolink($content){
    return preg_replace('#\>\>([0-9]+)#','<a href="#$1">>>$1</a>', $content);
}
```

Tested and works.